# PDA (Pushdown Automata) Trace - I don't understand the answer

Tags: trace, computation-theory, pushdown-automaton

I am learning about PDA, and I get how to trace a set of symbols or an alphabet for a given drawn PDA. However, I don't know how to trace for a given PDA (in written form) see below.

So this is a written PDA:

```
Q={s0,f}
Σ={a,b,c}
Γ={S,X,a,b,c}
F={f}
δ={((s0,ε,ε),(f,S)),
((f,ε,S)(f,aSc)),
((f,ε,S)(f,X)),
((f,ε,X)(f,bXc)),
((f,ε,X)(f,ε)),
((f,a,a)(f,ε)),
((f,b,b)(f,ε)),
((f,c,c)(f,ε))
}
```

The question asked:

```
Trace one possible computational path of your pushdown automaton from with
the input abccc. This string will not be accepted. Explain how you know that your computation has not accepted the input, that is, why the state and stack configuration after the input has been used up is not an accepting one.
```

The answer was:

```
State   Stack
s0      ε
f       S
f       aSc
f       Sc
f       Xc
f       bXcc
f       Xcc
f       cc
f       c
f       ε
```

I don't understand the stack symbols. I thought if there was a `ε` at the end of the stack that the input was accepted :S?

Would really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me

Thanks